# Change linked to Trailhead profile developer organization

Tags: trailhead

Actually is it possible to re-link Trailhead profile to another developer-edition organization?
If you know how can I contact Trailhead support, that would be nice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can "merge" your existing account to a new account. Note that the change is irreversible. See [this answer](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000kE5CIAU) for more info, but I'll include the essential text here.

---

> **Before We Begin**
>
> The following process assumes that the learner can still log into both
>   the ‘from’ and ‘to’ Trailhead accounts. If the learner can no longer
>   access the ‘from’ Trailhead account (e.g. they can no longer use their
>   previous corporate login for Salesforce), we, unfortunately, cannot
>   process the merge request.
>
> **One more thing (this time for realz)**
>
> Please note that the process of transferring Trailhead points and
>   badges from one account to another is irreversible. Once this
>   transfer/merge happens, there is no way for the learner to reverse the
>   process and move their Trailhead points/badges back to the original
>   account.
>
> **What we need to initiate the merge process**
>
> In order to transfer/merge Trailhead accounts, we need 2 things:
>
> (1) The user id for the ‘from’ Trailhead account
>
> To get this
>   information, do the following:
>
> Login to the ‘from’ Trailhead
>   account - the one you want to ‘give up’ and move points/badges from.
>
> Click on the ‘My Trailhead Account’ link under your name.
>
> Copy the value after the ‘userId=xxxx’ portion of the URL. This is the ‘from’ user id.
>
> (2) The user id for the ‘to’ Trailhead
>   account
>
> Repeat the steps above to get the user id for the ‘to’ Trailhead
>   account - the account that you want the points/badges transferred to.
>
> **Requesting the account merge**
>
> **Once you have the ‘from’ and ‘to’ user ids for your Trailhead account, please send an email to trailhead@salesforce.com with the
>   ’Account merge’ subject line
>   (mailto:trailhead@salesforce.com?subject=Account merge) and include
>   the two ids. We will be in touch with you as soon as the merge process
>   is complete.**